# Intellij / Grails development what to set to avoid PermGen errors?

Tags: tomcat, grails, intellij-idea, permgen

i am using IntelliJ to develop Grails application but as our application grows i am hitting the Permgen errors when using the Tomcat plugin. I have tried several combination in settings permgen size but they seem not to have any effect.

Any solution in dealing with these Permgen errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Run menu, select Edit Configurations, choose the configuration that executes run-app for your Grails app, then enter a value for permgen as shown in red below.

[image]

Comment: Solved my PermGen during development! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean that you get perm gen errors after redeploying several times?

If yes, this is a flaw with Tomcat itself.  The only way to fix it is to shut down Tomcat, restart it to empty out perm gen, and try again.

Grails itself contributes to the problem by using reflection to help enforce "convention over coding."  Reflection uses perm gen to do its work.  Hibernate can contribute as well; see

http://www.jroller.com/agileanswers/entry/preventing_java_s_java_lang

If you attach VisualVM 1.3.2 to the Tomcat process you'll be able to see all of memory, threads, etc.  Maybe that'll help you understand better if something else is happening.

Comment: Yes this happens after a few modifications, so i wanted to enlarge the permgen space for Tomcat. I can do that easy on a standalone tomcat but can find no place inside IntelliJ to configure the permgen space that IntelliJ passes through to the Tomcat plugin.

Comment: Enlarging perm gen will only delay it.  You'll still get the OOM error when perm gen fills up.

Comment: I know that it will delay but whenever i change a file stuff compiles etc and fills up the permgen. I am not able to solve that issue. So enlarging the permgen during development solves my problem. But i will take your advice and use VisualVM to search for potential problems later on!